# using Perl and WWW::Mechanize to get HTML with filled-in forms and save it to file

Tags: html, forms, perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to get a session recording of everything I do using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize). It is really important to have the HTML with the input fields filled and saved to a file.

My code:

```
$m->save_content($file); # Saves the page without any forms filled

$m->field('user_name', $user); #fills the form
# I need to save the html with the filled form
# $m->save_content($file_2); won't do it
# $m->dump_forms; shows that mechanize knows about the filled forms

$m->click('SUBMIT.x');
$m->save_content($file); # Too late, already in a different page
```

Any ideas? I have seen it working with [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) but I don't have access to the code.

I have tried everything I can come up with but nothing will update content with the values of `$m->forms()`.

EDIT: basically what I want is to have a function of the type:

`$updated_content = merge($m->content, $m->dump_forms);`

So when I save it I can see what the input that was given to the forms into a html slideshow.

I don't need to save the current state of the object or restore the session after it is closed.

Comment: Re your EDIT: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @simbabque I you look at selenium recorded sessions for example, you can see what the user has filled in the forms and stuff. I need something like that using mechanize.

Comment: The data Mechanize puts into the forms (before submitting) has to come from somewhere. To be more specific, it has to pass through your code. Why don't you just save it before/while/after you give it to Mechanize? You (your program) have to already know it or you couldn't hand it to Mechanize.

Comment: I know what data I am passing to Mechanize, but how do I merge it with the HTML without doing the same kind of processing that Mechanize is doing? Actually mechanize is using HTML::Form to process the data, but I would need to be dealing directly with the HTML using HTML::Treebuilder for instance. Then if I am going to be using that to modify my HTML then I might as well generate the POST or GET request from that and not use Mechanize at all. I obviously don't want to re-implement things like `$self->current_form->find_input('name')->check()` so I am looking for a smarter solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on what you are trying to achieve. The [`save_content`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-save_content-filename-) method saves only the content of the last HTTP response and not the entire `WWW::Mechanize` state.

If you want to store a `WWW::Mechanize` object so that browsing can proceed at any time from a given point, then you need to investigate *serializing* a blessed object.

My choice would be to use [`Data::Dump`](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDump). If you write

```
use Data::Dump 'dump';
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://www.mysite.com/path/resource.html');
$mech->form_with_fields(qw/ username password /);
$mech->set_fields( username => 'me', password => 'secret');

open my $dump, '>', 'mechanize_freeze.pl' or die $!;
print { $dump } dump $mech;
close $dump or die $!;
```

… then you should have a file that you can restore in a separate program using

```
my $oldmech = do 'mechanize_freeze.pl';
```

Comment: Thank your fast response, as my edit says I don't need to store the mechanize object to continue the session later, I need to get a html dump of the content after the forms have been filled (previous to it being submitted).